# Postgresql not supporting timestamp value on query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

```
DECLARE
MAX_upd_date_Entity_Incident timestamp without time zone;
MAX_upd_date_Entity_Incident := (SELECT LAST_UPDATE_DATE::timestamp FROM 
test.table_1 where TABLE_NAME='mac_incidents_d');

execute 'insert into test.table2 (column_name,schema_name,tablename) 
values(''col1'',''col2'',''col3'') from test.table3 X where X.dl_upd_ts::timestamp > '||
MAX_upd_date_Entity_Incident;
```

The above query is not getting executed, getting an error on the timestamp value, it's unable to read the variable `MAX_upd_date_Entity_Incident`.

Please suggest me if we need to cast timestamp to another format.

I am able to execute query in the SQL editor, but not using `execute`.

Comment: please quote error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass values as string literals. Use placeholders and pass them as "native" values.

Additionally you can't use the `values` clause if you want to select the source values from a table. An insert statement is **either** `insert into tablename (column_one, column_two) values (value_one, value_two)` **or** `insert into (column_one, column_two) select c1, c2 from some_table`

---

I also don't see the need for dynamic SQL to begin with:

```
insert into test.table2 (column_name,schema_name,tablename) 
select col1,col2,col3 
from test.table3 X 
where X.dl_upd_ts::timestamp > MAX_upd_date_Entity_Incident;
```

If you oversimplified your example and you indeed need dynamic SQL you should use something like this:

```
execute 'insert into test.table2 (column_name,schema_name,tablename) 
select col1,col2,col3) from test.table3 X where X.dl_upd_ts::timestamp > $1' 
    using MAX_upd_date_Entity_Incident;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's working but the issue still exist, the select query still extracts all the recs from table not on the date filter, it seems the timestamp variable is working.

Comment: @pradeeppanda: you have not supplied enough details to answer the question why the condition `where X.dl_upd_ts::timestamp > MAX_upd_date_Entity_Incident` doesn't return any rows. If I had to guess: your select statement that initializes the variable isn't returning what you think it does.

Comment: Yes, the query is returning value, if executed as normal query, and insert is also happening if you exec as query but when you put it as exec command it's not working. I need to use it as dynamic sql for my requirement.